# How to change text Home to icon Home on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to edit the breadcrumbs of website (MH Themes). It only is change the '**text Home**' (in echo line) to '**icon Home**' (`<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>`). I have try a ten times but I can't.

```
<?php
    
    /***** Breadcrumbs *****/
    
    if (!function_exists('mh_magazine_breadcrumb')) {
        function mh_magazine_breadcrumb() {
            if (!is_home() && !is_front_page()) {
                global $post;
                $mh_magazine_options = mh_magazine_theme_options();
                if ($mh_magazine_options['breadcrumbs'] == 'enable') {
                    $item_counter = 1;
                    $delimiter = '<span class="mh-breadcrumb-delimiter"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>';
                    $before_link = '<span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">';
                    $before_title = '<span itemprop="name">';
                    $close_span = '</span>';
                    echo '<nav class="mh-breadcrumb" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">' . $before_link . '<a href="' . esc_url(home_url()) . '" itemprop="item">' . $before_title . esc_html__('Home', 'mh-magazine') . $close_span . '</a>' . '<meta itemprop="position" content="' . $item_counter . '" />' . $close_span . $delimiter;
                    $item_counter++;
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete and missing some important parts to compile.

Comment: I dont think so. It is source of the themes. I recovered old data and was losing a lot of posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what's creating the Home text:

```
esc_html__('Home', 'mh-magazine')
```

That needs to be changed into the icon you want to display.

Comment: I have try to edit this code (esc_html__('Home', 'mh-magazine')). And the result is:.. "There has been a critical error o your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instruction. Learn more about debugging in Wordpress." :((

Comment: You might have just made a small mistake in your code. Try changing Home to some other word, just as a test, and see if that still breaks it.

Comment: Yeah, it is working very well when I change it to the different text. If I use the code, the display is original coding. And 2000 years later edit them, my web is unconsciously  T.T

Comment: Okay. What new code are you putting in, instead of the text? If I could take a look at that, I might be able to spot the issue.

Comment: I wanna change it to <i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> (the home icon)

Comment: Try changing
. esc_html__('Home', 'mh-magazine') . 

to 

. '<i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>' .

I think the issue might be that you're not quite getting in and out of the string and concatenation correctly.

Comment: It works very well. I missed typing the " and its not working. You are the kindest coder I have ever met. Thank you so much.